# Mongoose: updating item through POST JSON

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose

I have administation page with editing some model. When I get model I convert it into JSON and get something like this:

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "52d919c7ec31cffc17477767",
    "description": "Hello, teached",
    "points": 1300,
}
```

Here is my jade template

```
form(role='form', method='post', action='/admin/item')
            .form-group
                textarea.form-control#result(rows='20', name='result') !{JSON.stringify(item, null, '\t')}
            input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Send')
```

Here is my router code

```
app.post('/admin/item', function (req, res) {
    result = JSON.parse(req.body.result);
    Item.update({_id: result._id}, result, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('error');
        } else {
            res.send(result, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

And I always get an error, but when I update every field manually, like this:

```
result = JSON.parse(req.body.result);
Item.update({_id: result._id}, {description: result.description, ...
```

It magically updates. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete the `_id` field from the `result` object, otherwise Mongoose will assume you are trying to cast the `_id` field from a string rather than an `ObjectID`. You will also want to do this because I'm assuming updating the `_id` every time you update the document is probably not your desired behavior.

EDIT:

Also, if you are using the `bodyParser` middleware with Express, there is no need to parse the JSON yourself. `req.body` should return a parsed object literal from the body of your POST request. With that said, change your router to look like this to get things working:

```
app.post('/admin/item', function (req, res, next) {

  var id = req.body.result._id;
  delete req.body.result._id;

  Item.update({_id: id}, req.body.result, function (err, numAffected) {
    // Do something after update here
  });

});
```

Comment: How can I do this through 'result' variable?

Comment: Simply called `delete result._id`. Now everything works pefectly!

Comment: Yup – I added this to my edit as well. Glad to help!

Comment: So mongoose doesn't provide debug system? Unfortunately it doesn't show mongodb error like mysql.

Comment: Absolutely it does – the `err` argument in the callback for `#update()` should contain the errors you are looking for. Unfortunately, you are overriding with a generic string "error" instead of logging the `err` object to console or sending back to the client via `req.send(err)`

Comment: I did so - `req.send(err)`, but I always get empty object `{}`

Comment: A nodejs convention is for the first argument in a callback to contain any errors that might have occurred during the calling function. If no errors occur, `err` will be empty.